Lambda in VPC connection to S3/SES timeout despite having Endpoints defined
I have a Lambda inside a VPC that is unable to connect to S3 or SES; network timeout. I've seen the same question many times here but the answer in all of them is to add an Endpoint for each service. I've done that, but still get the timeouts.
The endpoints all have private DNS enabled, but DNS lookup that I do manually in the Lambda still return the public DNS entries, not the Endpoint entries.
I'm sure there's some other configuration I'm missing but I can't figure out what.

VPC with 6 subnets
DNS hostnames and resolution both enabled
Route table routing 172.31.* to local and everything else to an internet gateway.
Endpoints setup for S3, SES, and Secrets Manager with Private DNS enabled

The Lambda is in a VPC because I'm also using RDS, which is working.
Update: I tried adding a route from the S3 prefix list to the S3 endpoint but got an error * Cannot create or replace a prefix list route targeting a VPC Endpoint.* Screenshot added.









The S3 Endpoint type was Interface but needed to be Gateway, at least in my case. Creating the endpoint to the gateway automatically added it to the routing table just like @Tim said it would.
The SES connection was failing because the SES Client from the Node AWS SDK is not supported when used in a Lambda inside a VPC. Switching to use nodemailer solved that problem.


Ah, yes, I missed that you'd created an interface endpoint. You can use an interface endpoint, but they work a bit differently. For S3 and DynamoDB it's best to use the gateway endpoints, because they're free.
